# How to remove “onclick” with Mootools

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I want to click other element to remove attribute on click with element a ;

I used html like this:

```
<a href="#" data-value="all"  class="search-item" onclick="showCat(this)">全部商品</a>
```

And JS like this:

```
$$(".search-item").remove("click",showCat);
```

it is not working. How can I fix those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooTools API for removing attributes is [`Element:removeProperty`](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element#Element:removeProperty), and you can use like this:

```
$$(".search-item").removeProperty("onclick");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ethan use jQuery library

```
  jQuery('.search-item').removeProp('onClick').unbind('click')
```

Comment: I can't but i want it ;~ ╯▂╰ ~

Answer (score 0):

You can remove element's attribute like this:

```
$$(".search-item").setProperty("onclick", null);
```